# Write multiple values in a csv cell without brackets in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a list of objects. Each object have different attributes.
One of which is a list
I would like to export this objects to a csv file that looks like

```
a, "1,2,3"
b,"1,2,3"
```

so that the csv is readable in a Excel program

My code looks something like this:

```
final_list = []
for a in list:
        first_value = a.first_value
        list2 = []
        for b in a.list:
            list2.append(b)

        final_list.append(first_value)
        final_list.append(list2)
with open('file' ) as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(final_list)
    pass
```

which results in this csv rows with the brackets and quotes that i don't want

```
1, "['1','3','4']"
2,"['1','2','3']"
```

I need 2 values per row: `a` and `1,2,3` as string

Comment: i want 2 values a and 1,2,3 as string

Comment: It's better to edit your question instead of commenting below. Comments are disposable. Questions are the real asset for further readers. This time, I edited it for you using your comment, which gave you one upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do that:

```
    final_list.append(first_value)
    final_list.append(list2)
```

you create a row with a value and a list.

The `csv` module performs a `str` conversion when writing, which explains you see the string as it is printed when you debug in python.

Instead do:

```
    final_list.append(a.first_value)  # string
    final_list.append(",".join(a.list))  # composes a coma separated string with the contents of a.list
```

result:

```
a,"1,2,3"
```

(quotes protecting the commas so it is seen as a single cell)

Comment: You might want to make sure none of the values in your list have commas so that you can read the values back the way you wrote them. Something like `assert all(',' not in value for value in list2)` before appending it.

Comment: or write a csv row in the csv row?